# Traversing pymongo curser taking infinite time

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am using pymongo to access data from the mongo server. The server has billions of documents So I am using find and skip to access n documents at a time. I need to access only those documents which have "sample_key_XYZ" as _tag.

```
print('start',datetime.datetime.now())
a=db.collection.find({"_tag":re.compile('latest')}).skip(2000000).limit(2000)
print('end',datetime.datetime.now())
```

It's working fine cursor moves within a second. But when I tried to access data it stuck (takes hours to execute)
i.e

```
print('start',datetime.datetime.now())

    a=db.collection.find({"_tag":re.compile('sampe_key')}).skip(2000000).limit(2000)
    for doc in a:
        print(doc["_tag"])
        break
    print('end',datetime.datetime.now())
```

but if I change skip to a small number(2500) its execute very fast(1s)

('start', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 16, 59, 3, 685992))
('end', datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 16, 59, 3, 686293))
when used whithout doc traversing.

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you executing this against?

Comment: MongoDB version:3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, especially with it slowing down a lot as the skips increase, I suspect you're hitting [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13946). Have a look at the description in the ticket and check if you are seeing a large number of scanned objects/documents. From my experience that is the likely issue you're running into - basically MongoDB is fetching the documents before it skips them.

If this is indeed the case, the fix is to upgrade to a later point release of 3.6 as this issue was fixed in 3.6.9.